# How to deterministically generate large number of bitcoin addresses and monitor them

Tags: address, address-generation

I want to generate a large number of bitcoin addresses to provide visitors for each transaction and I want to monitor payments to those addresses.

How do I deterministically generate those large number of addresses and monitor payments to them.

Answer (score 1):

One options would be a bitcoinJ - bitcoin java library.

new ECKey().toAddress(new MainNetParams()).toString();

gives you a valid bitcoin address.

Answer (score 1):

For generating bulk wallets check out https://www.bitaddress.org

After that import the public key in to blockchain.info/wallet where you can monitor them

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blockonomics wallet watcher](https://www.blockonomics/blockonomics) to monitor large number of address. Their free plan allows for 50. You can easily upgrade to higher numbers.